# Flow typing a function that returns type where you can override some properties

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm trying to write a function that creates a typed object, but allows some of the properties to be overridden. `$Shape<T>` seems to do what I want here, since it ["Copies the shape of the type supplied, but marks every field optional."](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-shape)

However, when I spread `$Shape<A>` in a valid object of type `A`, where there is an optional property, flow errors:

```
// @flow

type A = {
  a: number,
  b: ?string,
}

function foo(attrs: $Shape<A>): A {
  return {
    a: 123,
    b: 'asd', // <- string incompatible with null
    ...attrs, 
  }
}

foo({ b: 'foo' })
```

[Try flow link](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AQVALygDeiooAhgFygB2ArgLYBGWATgDRmjM0D8AZxRsAlrQDmXAL7JI9WgGMUI2LVCRYsABQUUwgTQAkAZQAWFbAB5cAPgCUNfKXJssKemzXPylGgEYAJgBmLh8eGgByCgEAEwjQnwA6ZN19BJkZckQNbWJw0AiciNApOyA)

But if I remove the `...attrs` the error disappears. If I make the property required via `b: string`, the error also disappears.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `$Shape` seems like it's pretty broken, at least compared to how it's explained in the docs ([source](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7566)). I wouldn't be surprised if something from that is causing an issue with your types, which seem right based on how `...` and `$Shape` are described to work.

Answer (score 0):

you simply have the `?` on the wrong side of the `:`

```
type A = {
  a: number,
  b?: string,
}
```

EDIT:

After a discussion, the issue seems to be with defining the $Shape type inline with the param.

I had better luck setting it up outside, and also added an indexer to the type:

```
// @flow

type A = {
  [key: string]: string|number|null,
  a: number,
  b: string,
}
type ADetails = $Shape<A>;

function foo(attrs: ADetails): A {
  return {
    ...attrs,
  }
}

foo({ b: 'foo' })
```

Comment: Hmmm.... Well, that does seem to fix it, but it means something subtly different. `b?: string` means the property may not be present at all. `b: ?string` is more strict and says the property must be present and set to either `null` or a `string`.

Comment: if you want the type to be defined that way, do not use `?`, instead use: `b: null|string|undefined`

Comment: Yeah this doesn't work because [I can't actually set the property to `null`](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AQVALygDeoARgPwBcoAzigE4CWAdgOagC+iAxrC-VABDGviKkyNFgFdo0LkA). If it exists, it must be a string. And if I used `b?: ?string` I get the same error.

Comment: `string|null` works:

https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AQVALygDeoARgPwBcoAzigE4CWAdgOYA+LArtNKAF9EAY1gt6oAIY18RUmRo8+goA

Comment: But it doesn't when add in that spread operator https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AQVALygDeiooAhgFygB2ArgLYBGWATgDRmjMD8NAZxRsAlrQDmAHwbRoXAL7JI9WgGMUI2LVCRYsABQUUwgTQAkAZQAWFbAB5cAPgCUNfKXJssKem20fyShoARgAmAGYuQJ4aAHIKAQATWKjAgDoMoxNUxUVyRF0DYhjQWMLY0HlnIA

Comment: Ok, this is a bit odd. I had better luck setting up the $shape as it's own type. I also added an index to the type. 

Have a look: https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AQVALygDeiooA2gNZZoBcoAzigE4CWAdgOYC6Dz7bgB8OAVwC2AIywsRo6NAA0ZUAEMGYqTOXlJ-Vpy7KAvqkw5cAESwpVbaI0KgAJAGUAFquwAeXAD4AbmRIUQ4AYxQ2WA5QSFhYAApVFFZGBisbOwcASnSSFRYbURYY0nJydVAARgAmAGYdcr1QAHJVRgATFsbyADp+5NTG01NyRDjE4lBmlomW0GNsoA